# Fstest way to check for multiple string match of a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I am currently trying to find a string match from a dataframe that has list of actors and the movies that they acted in.

```
my_favourite_actors = ['Clint Eastwood','Morgan Freeman','Al Pacino']
```

| Actor | Movie |
| --- | --- |
| Morgan Freeman, Tim Robbins, Bob Gunton, William Sadler, Clancy Brown | The Shawshank Redemption |
| Marlon Brando, Al Pacino, James Caan | The Godfather |
| Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Gary Oldman, Maggie Gyllenhaal, Morgan Freeman | The Dark Knight |
| Henry Fonda, Lee Cobb, Martin Balsam | 12 Angry Men |
| Liam Neeson, Ralph Fiennes, Ben Kingsley | Schindler's List |
| Elijah Wood, Viggo Mortensen, Ian McKellen | The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King |
| John Travolta, Uma Thurman, Samuel Jackson | Pulp Fiction |
| Clint Eastwood, Eli Wallach, Lee Van Cleef | The Good, the Bad and the Ugly |
| Brad Pitt, Edward Norton, Meat Loaf | Fight Club |
| Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, | Inception |

I am currently using the following approach to do the string matching, but it's taking a very long time since the whole dataset almost has 100K rows.

```
def favourite_actor(movie_dataset):
    for actor in my_favourite_actors:
        movie_index= movie_dataset.loc[movie_dataset['Actor'].str.contains(actor , case=False)].index
        movie_dataset["_IsActorFound"].iloc[movie_index] = 1
```

*The rows that will find my favourite actors will insert the value of 1 to it's adjacent column of ['_IsActorFound']*

What can be an optimal and fast way to do the string match iteratively as my current code is taking extremely long time to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df['Actor'].str.contains('|'.join(my_favourite_actors), regex=True, case=False)
```

**Output**

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: Actor, dtype: bool
```

**Explanation**

Create a regex on the fly with the list, and then use `.str.contains()` accessor in pandas. `|` means set to `True` if any one element of the list matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the apply function as follows:

```
def find_actor(s, actors):
    for actor in actors:
        if actor in s.lower():
            return 1
    
    return 0
```

`df['Actor'].apply(find_actor, actors=my_favourite_actors.lower())`

The advantage is that it only checks until one of the actors is found. Please note that for strings the apply function is ok to use because `str.contains()` is also not vectorized under the hood.